# Pycharm: python manage.py runserver returns nothing

Tags: python, pycharm, django-manage.py, django-runserver

I am struggling to get the http link from pycharm. I must say I am pretty new to software engineering and I am only following tutorials. I am currently stuck on this problem and I can't find any answer.
H[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SrHB.png)ope someone can help me to figure this out.

looking forward to sort out the problem and understand the nature of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `manage.py` is empty, which is why running it does nothing.

You can copy in a fresh copy of `manage.py` from [the repository's template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/project_template/manage.py-tpl) if you've obliterated your own -- just remember to change that `{{ project_name }}` to match your project.

Comment: okay I will do , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`manage.py` is empty, therefore it will execute nothing. When you are executing `python manage.py runserver`, it will go to manage.py and execute all the code in there. However, if you are wondering what about the `runserver` parameter? Well, in your file you have not told python to handle extra parameters, so it won't.

It seems that you have deleted all the boilerplate code that came when you created the `Django` project.
To solve this, you can simply copy the code from the tutorial or from a repository you are following.

Comment: thanks for the information I will try to sort it out